# PowerShell CRUD with WCF Data Services (OData)?

Tags: powershell, wcf, powershell-2.0, odata

I am trying to perform CRUD against WCF Data Services (OData). The Read portion is pretty well documented across the web… it’s the Create, Update and Delete that I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the documentation, have you looked at odata.org: http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#CreatingnewEntries
It has a description and samples of all the common CRUD operations against an OData services.

You can also write a sample client application using any OData client (for example the .NET one) and use something like fiddler to see what requests are being made against the service, if you need to see the exact payload shape for your particular service.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [REST PowerShell module](http://poshcode.org/691) that Jaykul wrote.